# Why does the passport.js create an Unauthorized page on its own when authentication fails? how can I redirect it to a special page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, pug

here is my router:

```
  router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    body('backurl').trim().escape();
    let referrer = req.get('Referrer')
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.render('login', {
        message: 'Unable to login, the password or the username are wrong',
        backUrl: referrer
      });
    }
    if (req.body.backurl == null || req.body.backurl == 'http://localhost:3000/signup' || req.body.backurl == 'http://localhost:3000/login') {
      return res.redirect('/yourcourses');
    }
    
    return res.redirect(req.body.backurl);
  }
);
```

When the user and the local authentication works it does work perfectly, however on fail I want to render the login page again with a message and a variable, however on failure the website simply makes an empty page with the word "unauthorized" on it without anything else, how do I fix it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When authentication in Passport fails, the `next()` function is not called, the middleware chain is stopped and a generic error is returned, that's why your code isn't executing.

The solution could be to create another route, for example `'/loginfail'`, and moving in there the code that re-renders the 'login' page with the referrer and the error message.

Then, modify the call to `passport.authenticate` to include an options object, like this:

```js
passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/loginfail' });
```

So, when authentication fails, Passport calls the route you specified.

Comment: Yeah but I want to also render changing variables into the failureRedirect, and your way doesnt help it...

Comment: Did you try moving the code? You create a route.get('/loginfail', (req,res,next) and in there you move the code of your actual login route starting from the line 'let referrer...' up to the end of the first if... except you won't need that 'if' because if this route is hit, you are certain the login failed.